# Alterar porta ou outra coisa no IIS Express. Tem como?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis

Como posso alterar uma porta ou outra coisa no IIS Express do Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Botão direito no `.csproj` > Properties.

Vá na opção **Web** e altere a porta em **Project Url**:

[image: IIS Porta]

Comment: Então isso eu já fiz e sempre me pede para eu criar um diretório virtual. Devo fazer isso? E por que ele sempre aponta o caminho físico para C:\ProjetoWebApi se eu já deletei esse diretório? Isso é que eu não estou entendendo.

Comment: Sim, o diretório virtual sempre está vinculado a um projeto, e a troca de porta pede uma nova configuração. Não entendi qual o problema do caminho físico.